# Splitting out multiple intermediate changes in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

We have a very unfortunate situation where a new feature branch was made from a second, unrelated feature branch that had been put on hold rather than from default. There's multiple changesets within both feature branches and while most changed files are unrelated several high level project files that have edits on both branches. Default has also had several updates and merges during this time too. Thankfully the intermediate feature hasn't been updated concurrently with the new feature. I've looked into various commands and options available and lost how to best fix this situation. The tree currently looks roughly like:

```
Default -- Various edits and merges -- tip
   \
    \-- Named Branch 1 (15 changes) -- Named Branch 2 (30 edits)
```

I want to get to a point where default has the changes from Named Branch 2 but none from Named Branch 1. I also want a branch that has the changes from Named Branch 1 available for when we return to this feature.

I suspect there's no nice easy way to do this, and there's going to be some messy parts in the history, however I am at a loss at how to start going about this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg graft` can cherry-pick changesets from one branch to another.  Update to the destination branch, then graft the revisions you want to copy by running, for example:

```
hg graft 8 9 10
```

Conflicts will be handled using the normal merge process.

If you use `TortoiseHg`, select the changesets to graft to the current selected changeset, then right-click and select `Graft Selected to local...`:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark, a few nasty merge conflicts but nothing too painful. Though the new graph is gloriously ugly when Tortoise tries to display it :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to move the entire *branch 2*, you could consider using `rebase`. Make a clone of the repository and try this:

```
hg rebase --source <first branch2 rev> --dest <new parent in default> --keepbranches
```

This will in principle transform the history to what it should have been. However:

1. You may have to resolve conflicts arising when `<first branch2 ver>` gets moved to a new parent.
2. Since `rebase` rewrites history, you'll have to get everyone to cooperate in synchronizing their repositories. Whether that's feasible or worth the trouble in your case I can't say, but it's not that difficult: Assuming everyone has pushed any changes in branch 2, they can pull the new history and then get rid of the obsolete version of branch 2 with `hg strip`:

   ```
   hg strip <first branch2 rev>
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Alexis, while this might be the more correct answer in many respects I'll go with the graft approach. It has the advantage of not messing with history nor requiring syncing.

Comment: That is indeed a big advantage if you have multiple users! Also I left out the detail that to rewrite the history, you must tweak the phase of changesets that have been "published"...